# "In the election phase, 10 candidates advance..." really 10?

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

Note at [2013 Moderator Election page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3) states:

> In the election phase, **10 candidates** advance to final community voting...

But there are **three** candidates, not **10**, as indicated by another note at this very page. Could this be fixed?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ZeN.png]

Comment: It's the generic text and surely really means "up to to 10".

Comment: @ChrisF thanks, "**up to** 10" would make a perfect sense in this note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added an "up to" when there are more slots than candidates - will be there in the next build